# Find the number of continuations and variations of $f(x)=x^4+3x^3+2x^2+6x-1=0$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

I was reading about Descartes rule of signs . The prequisites for using this celebrated rule is to know the continuations and variations of the coefficients of the polynomials . However, I am having a confusion in that . In fact, these things are not given in a "clear" way in most books (as I observed atleast, in my case). So, let's say if I have a polynomial with $$f(x)=x^4+3x^3+2x^2+6x-1=0$$. Now, I want to calculate the number of continuations. I think the number of continuations in this case is $3$. This is because we consider consecutive terms two at a time. Is this correct? Or the continuations will be $1$? This is creating a confusion for me. For the following theorem: Let $f(x)$ be a  polynomial, with real coefficients and $v, v'$ are respectively the number of variations and continuations of signs in the sequence of its coefficients. If all roots of $f(x)=0$ are real. Prove that the equation has $v$ positive roots and $v'$ negative roots. In order to have a clear perception about the above theorem , we must essentially have a clear perception about the number of continuations and variations. So ,I just need a clarification upon this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Descartes+rule+of+signs+ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: The Descartes rule is not about continuations or variations , it is about sign changes (here $2$). The number of positive real roots (considering multiplicity) is then the number of sign changes or an even number less.

Comment: What you mean is probably sturm's theorem.

Comment: Почему так $x^4+3x^4$?

Comment: @Peter https://homework.study.com/explanation/x-4-plus-16x-2-plus-7x-11-0-descartes-rule-of-signs-to-find-the-nature-of-the-roots-of-the-equation.html

Comment: @VadimChernetsov Это была опечатка... Я отредактировал это...

Comment: @AnneBauval I have edited my post a bit...It was a typo...

Comment: Descartes's rule as I know it: If all the roots of $f(x)$ are real then the number of positive roots is equal to the number of variations and the number of negative roots is equal to the number of continuations.

Comment: @Piquito True, but these concepts are required in order to understand Descartes rule as you mention as well as other deductions related to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sequence of real numbers none of which is zero, the sign of 2 consecutive terms may be same or different. If same, then increase the number of "continuations" by 1 Else increase the number of "variations" by 1. Both continuations and variations start from zero.

Your equation first has to be written such that the powers are descending:
$f(x)=x^4+3x^3+2x^2+6x-1$

In your case, you have the sequence: $1,3,2,6,-1$

(1,3) same

(3,2) same

(2,6) same

(6,-1) different

So, continuations = $3$ and variations=$1$

Another example - The sequence:
$1, 3, -5, -7, 9, -4, 10, 2$

(1,3)  same

(3,-5)  different

(-5,-7) same

(-7,9)  different

(9,-4)  different

(-4,10) different

(10,2)  same

Adding up, continuations =$3$ and variations=$4$

Sources:

[GoogleBooks-College Algebra and Trigonometry](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=HSAFAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA291&dq=descartes%20rule%20of%20signs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGiM2phoP8AhVSxhoKHZROBcYQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=descartes%20rule%20of%20signs&f=false)

[Soruce-2](https://www.kharagpurcollege.ac.in/studyMaterial/215526Study%20materials_5_2nd%20Sem_MTMGE_GE2T_Unit%201%20by%20Kousik%20Bhattacharya.pdf)

Comment: Sorry...I made a typo in my post ...I have edited it...if you verify with the edited one it will be very helpful...Thank you!

Comment: I changed the answer. Please change the function in the post title to go with the body of the question.

Comment: Thank you! So my answer is correct right? And yes changing it right away...

Comment: As stated and shown, continuous =3. You are correct.

Comment: Thank you! I  do get it now...

Comment: Glad I could help.